# Orbitals SPDF. Why they named like that?

Tags: orbitals

I know there are orbitals named S, P, D and F.

1. But why they named like that. is there any significance for the letter?
2. Is there any order in filling the orbitals?

Comment: In my old memory they were ; Sharp , Pronounced, Diffuse, and Foggy based on the film images.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the abstract of [Structure of the Line Spectra of the Elements](https://books.google.com/books?id=vp0wAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA674&dq=sharp%20principal%20diffuse&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinrZH5v__NAhUDx2MKHUw1CzEQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=sharp%20principal%20diffuse&f=false) as published in the 1890 Journal of the Chemical Society.

> There are three kinds of series — principal, sharp (well-defined), and diffuse (ill- defined). The principal series form the most vivid lines in the spectra, and only occur in the first, periodic group ; next come the diffuse (really double) lines ...

See also [On the Structure of the Line Spectra of the Chemical Elements](https://books.google.com/books?id=b5MOAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA333&dq=dewar%20%22diffuse%20sharp%20and%20principal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibpKTXxP_NAhUH8GMKHcwVDoMQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=dewar%20%22diffuse%20sharp%20and%20principal%22&f=false), also from 1890 by Rydberg:

> Liveing and Dewar were the first to remark the existence of the series, as well as their different appearances. They are of three kinds : *diffuse*, *sharp*, and *principal* series. The first two are formed by the above-mentioned doublets or triplets ...

Later, ["fundamental" was added](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21837/about-the-meaning-of-the-names-of-f-orbitals/21839#21839).

For more information see [The Origin of the s, p, d, f Orbital Labels](http://www.che.uc.edu/jensen/W.%20B.%20Jensen/Reprints/137.%20s,%20p,%20d,%20f.pdf) *J. Chem. Educ.*, 2007, 84, 757-758

Comment: Can you please add an image of how the different spectra actually look like?